# Show Collections in MongoDB throwing

Tags: mongodb, scripting, mac-os-x

I am connecting to MongoDB hosted on EC2 instance of AWS. I am connecting through ssh command.
Upon entering the command "show collections", I am getting uncaught exceptions. Please see the sequence below. Can you let me know how can I start seeing the collections again when putting in the "Show collections" command?

> show dbs
>   admin    0.031GB
>   cool_db  (empty)
>   local    0.031GB
>   users    0.031GB
>   use users
>   switched to db users
>   show collections
>   2019-08-26T18:46:15.280+0000 E  QUERY    [js] uncaught exception: Error: listCollections failed: {
>       "ok" : 0,
>       "errmsg" : "no such cmd: listCollections",
>       "code" : 59,
>       "bad cmd" : {
>           "listCollections" : 1,
>           "filter" : {

```
    },
    "nameOnly" : true,
    "authorizedCollections" : true
}
```

} :
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13
DB.prototype._getCollectionInfosCommand@src/mongo/shell/db.js:834:15
DB.prototype._getCollectionNamesInternal@src/mongo/shell/db.js:906:12
DB.prototype.getCollectionNames@src/mongo/shell/db.js:915:12
shellHelper.show@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:893:9
shellHelper@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:790:15
@(shellhelp2):1:1

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the output of `version()` and `db.version()` in the `mongo` shell? It looks like you are using a newer version of the `mongo` shell with an older (pre-3.0) version of MongoDB server. The major version of shell & server (x.y)  should ideally match.

Comment: The version on shell is 4.2 and the version on server is 3.6. Didn't know that could cause an issue. Is there a way to fix this without uninstalling and re-installing the mongodb?

Comment: The `listCollections` command was added in MongoDB 3.0 so this would be an unexpected error for a 3.6 server. Are you sure the server is 3.6? What is the exact server version (x.y.z)? If you are connecting via `ssh` and running `mongo` on the remote host (where the `mongod` is), it also seems unusual to have a different version of the shell from the server. Are you port forwarding `ssh`? The easiest fix to ensure compatibility would be installing a matching version of the `mongo` shell. Your 4.2 shell should be displaying a message on startup: `WARNING: shell and server versions do not match`.

Comment: Yes, I am getting the warning that you have mentioned above. The MongoDB server version is 2.6.12 not 3.6. Apologies. Is there a way to upgrade the Mongo server version through some shell command?

Comment: Upgrading the MongoDB server requires access to the host environment, so you could upgrade via a Linux `bash` shell but would not be able to do so only using the `mongo` shell. MongoDB 2.6 reached End of Life in Oct 2016, so you definitely should be planning to upgrade. In the interim I would download a 2.6 version of the `mongo` shell as a **lot** has changed since then.